# How to fix context.password coming null in /Token request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, token, asp.net-authorization

**Class: Startup**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            //enable cors origin requests
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var myProvider = new ClinicServerProvider();
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
                Provider = myProvider
            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        }
    }
```

**Class: ClinicServerProvider**

```
 public class ClinicServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private readonly BoilerplateDbContext _context;

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(_context);
            string epass = Crypto.EncryptString(context.Password);
            var user = uow.UserRepository.Get(x => x.Password == epass && x.UserName == context.UserName && x.IsActive==true).FirstOrDefault();
// Other custom code here.

}
}
```

In the above method..
I am getting **context.Password** coming null always..

 [image]

Is anybody knows what is the reason?

Comment: You didn't show how you are actually calling that /token.

Comment: @Evk I am calling from postman passing the access details.

Comment: @Evk https://snag.gy/ABWMdx.jpg check this.
previously working but don't know why it stopped working.. now it getting null in password. username is coming.

Answer (score 0):

On method GrantResourceOwnerCredentials once you add claims after validating the username password you need to add this claim:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
```

Comment: I am not getting the password. 
like context.username is filling ok.
but context.password coming null.

Answer (score 0):

A belated answer but in case someone may end up in a similar situation in future...

The `x-www-form-urlencoded` key names in your request data must be named `username` and `password`.

If the key names are named differently, `context.UserName` and `context.Password` will always result in  `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a problem similar to your's but my problem is `context.UserName = ""`. I try to hard check my code but I don't found any mistake.

I test the request by Postman. I found the cause of problem in parameter on Postman.
The solution is to delete the parameter `username` and re-create again.

[Parameter on Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnUGC.jpg)

I think this solution may will help you.